# Why can I get no satisfaction trying to add margin or padding between an image and some text?

Tags: html, css

I want an image on the left and three pieces of text on the right. I've got that, but trying to add some space between them is proving to be an exercise in futility. I've tried adding both padding-left and margin to the css, but they ignore them like a cheerleader does a nerd.

The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GwYJH/

Here's my HTML:

```
<a id="mainImage" class="floatLeft" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1456334050" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img height="200" width="160" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51ETjedyMAL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg"></img></a>

<div class="category">Picaresque Satire</div>
</br>
<div class="title">the Zany Time Travels of Warble McGorkle</div>
</br>
<div class="author">Blackbird Crow Raven</div>
</br>
```

...and the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
.floatLeft {
    float: left;
}
.category {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: Orange;
    padding-left: 25;
    margin: 25;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Calibri, Candara, serif;
    color: Yellow;      
}
.author {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: White;
}
```

I also want each piece of text to wrap if the viewbox narrows. IOW, "Picaresque Satire" should become:

```
Picaresque
Satire
```

...if there's not enough space to fit on one line; what it's doing now is moving below the image if it runs out of space (then it will break as I want it to if it gets squished even more).

Comment: Check your syntax. You should specify units for your margins/padding: `margin: 25px;`. Also, try `<br />` instead of `</br>` (or remove them entirely). http://jsfiddle.net/GwYJH/5/

Comment: Add the `padding` to the `image` and everything else can stay the same, if it pleases you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some suggestions for you. Fist of all, use this code to get the spaces.

```
.floatLeft {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

The, set the width to the `.category`, so you wrap the text

```
.category {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: Orange;
    padding-left: 25;
    width:30px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GwYJH/)

Comment: The width property is the thing that worked - thanks! (and showdev's comment).

Answer (score 3):

```
    #mainImage {
        margin-right:15px;
    }

   .category p {
   word-wrap:break-word;
    }
```

Demo here:http://jsfiddle.net/GwYJH/8/

How the word wraps (i.e. if it wraps to the right hand side of the image or below it) is wholly dependent on the width of the containing element.

Answer (score 2):

Non-zero padding and margin values require a unit to be specified.  I assume you wanted pixels:

```
padding-left: 25px;
margin: 25px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GwYJH/6/

Old versions of IE would allow you to omit the unit, but modern standards compliant browsers do not.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have (px) defined on the padding-left and margin.  Remove margin and only use padding-left on all of the divs.

Use this code instead:

```
.category {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: Orange;
    padding-left: 25px;

}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Calibri, Candara, serif;
    color: Yellow;
    padding-left: 25px;

}
.author {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: White;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```